# Any Java lib for visualizing decision trees?

Tags: java, tree, visualization

Is there any Java lib for visualizing decision trees classifiers?

Answer (score 2):

[**jBoost**](http://jboost.sourceforge.net/index.html) is a widely used Java boosting implementation, and comes with a few [visualization tools](http://jboost.sourceforge.net/doc.html#visualization). You can run them on jBoost's classifier output from the command line, or invoke from your own application.